# Unknown alien movie - Astronaut has sex with twins, chest-bursting fun ensues

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space, horror, astronauts

So, this astronaut comes back home from a mission on which he's unknowingly picked up some alien, you know, basic stuff.

Except he then has sex with two women, sisters, possibly twins... I think it then goes something like: they both get impregnated and the aliens erupt from their stomachs and kill him or they turn into aliens, something of that sort. I remember it being really graphic, although, I was not more than 7-10 years old.

The movie (well, the first 10 minutes of it!) obviously left me with some huge trauma since I still remember that scene, so please, be sure to reply if you know anything about it.

Answer (score 12):

I'm fairly sure this is [Species II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species_II)

> After their return, the three astronauts - Ross, as well as Dennis
>   Gamble and Anne Sampas - are examined by the space agency doctor,
>   Orinsky, and quarantined to prevent them from engaging in sexual
>   activity for ten days. However, at a fundraiser honoring the
>   astronauts, Patrick quickly disregards this advice and makes out with
>   a woman referred to as the Debutante (Lindsey, in the Novelization) in
>   a lounge (his fiancé, Melissa, claims that he is resting, so she may
>   not be aware of his infidelity). **When he is called to give a speech,
>   the Debutante/Lindsey invites him up to her room to have sex. After
>   making his speech, he visits her room and finds her and her sister
>   (actually her friend Claudia, in the novelization) both waiting for
>   him. Patrick then has sex with the Debutante/Lindsey, then her
>   sister/friend. As Patrick has sex again, the Debutante/Lindsey
>   undergoes an accelerated pregnancy; within minutes, her stomach bursts
>   open to release a newborn hybrid of human and alien DNA.** This seems to
>   sequenize with the alien DNA in Patrick as he sprouts tentacles, which
>   the sister/friend notices; Patrick continues having sex, despite her
>   pleas, leaving her to the same fate (which is never seen).

The scene you're referring to can be seen [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2gqidu) at timecode 20:00 onwards
Warning, this link is very NSFW due to PG:13 nudity and creature-effects.

Comment: +1 This is the right answer. Awful sequel to an already pretty weak movie. The only reason I wanted to like *Species* was because of H.R. Giger, but it wasn't enough.

Comment: Not sure if I want to rewatch it now, it sounds horrible, but thank you so much!

Comment: @Richard (And yeah, you beat me to it :P )

Comment: @AndresF. - I quite liked the first one. It may be that I'm sufficient shallow as to be distracted from the abysmal plot by the sight of Natasha Henstridge's persistent nudeyness.

Comment: @Richard There was that, too.

Comment: What a nice little nope.